# Why are task callback `visible` values FALSE?

Tags: r, callback

In the [documentation for Top-level Task Callbacks in R](http://developer.r-project.org/TaskHandlers.pdf), a callback is sent four arguments: `expr`, `value`, `ok`, and `visible`. These mostly make sense. But `visible` is defined as:

> whether the output from the task was printed or not.

I interpret this as meaning when `visible==TRUE` something was output to the console (or wherever) and when `visible==FALSE` nothing was output to the console.

Question: I would expect `visible==TRUE` when `cat` or `print` are used because there is visible output. But the `visible` argument is actually `FALSE` in these cases.

Example:

```
addTaskCallback(function(expr,value,ok,visible) {cat(visible,'\n'); TRUE}, name='ex')
1 # makes sense, something is printed
x <- 1 # makes sense, nothing is printed
x # makes sense, something is printed
print(x) # ???
cat(x) # ???

removeTaskCallback('ex') # cleanup
```

Shouldn't `visible` be `TRUE` in the last two examples? If not, why?

Comment: +1 for the cleanup! I looked at this Q then forgot and have been wondering why my console keeps printing TRUE TRUE! :-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe that `visible` refers to whether the *returned value* from a function is printed, not whether the function prints anything during execution. Note that most `print` methods actually end with an `invisible()` call, to return the printed object invisibly. Similarly, the printed output from `cat` is distinct from its returned value, which is invisibly `NULL`.

Comment: That makes sense (and thus explains why `capture.output` differs from `value` as sent to the callback). So there must be some internal process at work by which R distinguishes `invisible` from `return`? And similarly distinguishes the visibility of `x` versus `print(x)`?